# PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber NullPointException

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception, telephonymanager

```java
package com.example.helloworld;
    
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;

public class IncomingCallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String TAG = "PHONE STATE";
    private static String mLastState;
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onReceive()");

        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        if (state.equals(mLastState)) {
            return;
        } else {
            mLastState = state;
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

if (incomingNumber == null ) {
                Log.i("call-state", " : NULL");
            } else {
                if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "call Active", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "No call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(context, incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            final String phone_number;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                phone_number = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(incomingNumber, Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
            } else {
                phone_number = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(incomingNumber);
            }
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, CallingService.class);
            serviceIntent.putExtra(CallingService.EXTRA_CALL_NUMBER, phone_number);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

I checked and tried all the stackoverflow questions and answers.
However, the program throws an Exception at:

```java
phone_number = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(incomingNumber, Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
```

This is the Exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
> com.example.helloworld.IncomingCallBroadcastReceiver:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'boolean java.lang.String.startsWith(java.lang.String)' on a null
> object reference

Thus, I guess that the following is returning null:

```java
String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

I tried many other things such as adding `READ_CALL_LOG`. But it didn't work.
even the toast message didn't show.
Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Don't guess, check what is null. For example with the debugger or by logging some values. Finding out what's wrong is the first step to solve it.

Comment: Obvious question would be: what API / Permissions / device are you using? As telephonyManager is deprecated on API 29

Comment: @ibecar I'm using API 28

Comment: @Henry I checked it and it returned null!

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior of the API, [according to the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER) there are two cases in which you'll get null for `EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER`:

1. If your app does not have `READ_CALL_LOG` permission, which you already said you have in your app, however note that it's not enough to add it to your manifest, you need to implement [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) in order to actually receive it.
2. If the current state change is anything other than `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` => `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` or `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE` => `EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK`. I only see you're checking the value of the new state before getting that extra and ignoring the previous state.

I can add another thing that I know of, when your app has `READ_CALL_LOG` permission you'll be getting TWO broadcasts for each event, one where `EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` is always null, and another same state-change where `EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` will possibly have a value (according to the cases above), so instead of ignoring a duplicate state change (`if (state.equals(mLastState)) return`) you should skip it only if the value of `EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` is null.

Here's the relevant snippet from the docs:

> This extra is only populated for receivers of the
> ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED broadcast which have been granted the
> Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG and
> Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permissions.
>
> For incoming calls, the phone number is only guaranteed to be
> populated when the EXTRA_STATE changes from EXTRA_STATE_IDLE to
> EXTRA_STATE_RINGING. If the incoming caller is from an unknown number,
> the extra will be populated with an empty string. For outgoing calls,
> the phone number is only guaranteed to be populated when the
> EXTRA_STATE changes from EXTRA_STATE_IDLE to EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.